# Reset the comment count

Tags: comments, counter

How do I reset the comment count visible in the permalink when a user is posting a new comment? For an example see the picture below:

["#comments-..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gownK.png)

I have deleted all comments on my site but the 'counter' keeps counting.

The comment count is caused by a default Wordpress code (in the wp-comments-post.php file) shown belown:

```
$location = empty( $_POST['redirect_to'] ) ? get_comment_link( $comment ) : $_POST['redirect_to'] . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;
```

Comment: would you put in the code please..

Comment: Thanks, totaly forgotten. I've edited the question. Its a default code of Wordpress.

Comment: No one who can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I fixed it by made a dummy comment on a post. Then Comments section in Admin Dashboard recounted. Then simply delete that dummy comment will reset it to zero.